# Enabling Microsoft XML DOM Document add-on in IE8 causes stack overflow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Enabling the "Microsoft XML DOM Document" add-on in IE8 causes a stack overflow popup error on some page loads. Would anyone know why? It does not appear that leaving this add-on disabled has any impact on JavaScript-enabled sites.
[image]

Comment: What does the stack look like?

Comment: I wish I knew! IE8 developer tools (F12) suck, and there is no way to display a stack trace that I can tell. IE9, Chrome, and Firefox show no warnings or errors. You can see this error if you've got IE8 and go to www.vitacost.com and click around the top nav category menu items.

Comment: Is it a JavaScript stack that is overflowing, or a native stack?  Your comment implies JavaScript, in which case I misunderstood and probably won't be much help.

Comment: Yeah JS stack. IE8 isn't crashing.